# how can i delete docker-credential-pass

Tags: docker

I have a problem with docker login and pass, when I can't find a solution to this problem I decide to uninstall the pass

I delete pass, `config.json` but when I want to connect a docker hub

`sudo docker login`

Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.

```
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: no credentials server URL, out: no credentials server URL
```

`sudo docker logout`

Removing login credentials for `https://index.docker.io/v1/`

```
WARNING: could not erase credentials:

https://index.docker.io/v1/: error erasing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: pass not initialized: exec: "pass": executable file not found in $PATH:
```

I don't know what I can do

can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

Deleting the file `/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain` worked for me.

```
rm /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain
```

If the above one doesn't work then try to Remove the line `"credsStore": "osxkeychain"` from `~/.docker/config.json`

Comment: when i do that i have another problem                                                                  
WARNING: could not erase credentials:
https://index.docker.io/v1/: error erasing credentials - err: exec: "docker-credential-pass": executable file not found in $PATH, out: ``

Comment: @hadir andddd I should have read the first comment. Now I have this error.

Comment: thanks, i just remove `"credsStore"` field from `~/.docker/config.json`.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue but I'm using github container registry and In my case there was no credentials in config.json.

**Note:** This scenario may be created when you try to logout for other container repository service(e.g docker hub) and login to another (In my case ghcr.io which is github)

**Solution:**
Logout from old service if you have already login:

```
docker logout
```

Now ename docker-credential-secretservice e.g

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/docker-credential-secretservice /usr/bin/docker-credential-secretservice.broken
```

Next try to logout now.

```
sudo docker logout
```